# c# access clients google analytics data

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I want to build a software that clients register to and allow it to get the google analytics data of their site and analyze it.

I found the google api documentation website and found .NET libraries - but they all seem to require a username and password - which I don't think if fair to ask of my clients.

Is there any other credentials I can ask of my clients during registration that will allow my software access to their analytics data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only solution Google provides to retrieve GA without requiring the GA account info from the user is [Google Analytics superProxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy).  I'm not entirely sure if this will work out as far as interacting with standalone applications, since it does involve pointing to a URL...